# Pregunta! - Compilación de jar con librerías (*.class) de SQLite en proyecto NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, sqlite, class, build

no es un problema, es mas una pregunta de porque funciona lo que voy a explicar.

Resulta que tengo un proyecto con SQLite, y vi en un ejemplo de proyecto (**no me acuerdo de donde lo saqué**) donde las (*.class) estaban metidas dentro del proyecto, como se puede ver en la imagen con las flechas rojas...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ya **no hace falta** tener que poner en el proyecto los drivers (Librería) de SQLite,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

porque cuando compilas el JAR esas librerías ya están dentro de él, claro... el ejecutable aumenta de tamaño, pero eso da igual, porque funciona bien, y mejor... cuando creas un EXE del JAR en windows (con **launch4j**).

Mi pregunta es: **¿De donde sacó la persona que hizo ese proyecto la solución?**

Answer (score 0):

El jar no es más que un zip con los .class, alguna meta-información, y ficheros de recursos.

Supongo que la persona que hizo ese proyecto simplemente descomprimió un JAR en el directorio src, y el netbeans trata esos ficheros como "recursos" (algo que no procesa pero que copia en el JAR).

Supongo que quería tener todas las clases de su programa en un único jar, pero

**NO TRABAJES ASÍ**

Problemas:

- No es estándar, y confundirá a otros programadores como te ha confundido a tí.
- Si quieres actualizar la versión del driver tienes que modificar el proyecto.
- Adivinar qué versión del driver usas es mucho más dificil que si el proyecto incluye mysql-4.5.3.jar
- Si decides usar otra librería de BD (p.ej. oracle) puedes dejarte allí las clases olvidadas.
- Si usas otro IDE o herramienta, igual no trata bien esos archivos (p.ej con Maven los recursos tienen que estar en una estructura de carpetas separada para que los copie al jar).

Comment: Gracias SJuan por tu respuesta!!!